# Magento filter on new colunm on catalog_product grid not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product, grid, filter

I'm trying to add a column on the catalog_product grid on magento 1.9.0.1.
I want my column to contain the number of images of each product.

I have created an extension for that.

In config.xml

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_before>
    <observers>
        <event_sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
            <type>singleton</type>             
            <class>Group_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>catalogProductGridCollectionLoadBefore</method>
        </event_sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_before>
<core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    <observers>
    <add_column_product_by_categ_nbr_image>
        <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Group_Module_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>addNbImagesColonne</method>
        </add_column_product_by_categ_nbr_image>
    </observers>
</core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
```

In observer.php :

```
public function addNbImagesColonne($observer){
            $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

            if(get_class($block) == 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid'){
                $block->addColumnAfter('nbrImages', array(
                        'header'    => "Number of images",
                        'width'     => '100px',
                        'index'     => 'nbImage',
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'filter_index' => 'cpemg.nbImage',
                ), 'status');
            }
        }
public function catalogProductGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {

        $collection = $observer->getCollection();//get the collection

        $collection->calculateSizeWithoutGroupClause = true;//Correct the number of row return
        $select = $collection->getSelect();

        $select->joinLeft(
                array('cpemg' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery')),
                'cpemg.entity_id=e.entity_id',
                array(
                        'nbImage' => new Zend_Db_Expr(' COUNT(cpemg.value_id)'),
                )
        );
        $select->group('e.entity_id');

    }
```

My column is working fine but when I try to filter products by the number of image, I have no error print and my grid does not show.

Could you tell me where my mistake is ?

Comment: I cannot help you with your problem, but I can highly recommend https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl to do this.

Answer (score 0):

filter_index is afaik the column you want to filter on. Did you add a column `nbImage` to your table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`? If not, try to remove the `cpemg` right before